# How to define multiple sitemaps in a sitemap?

Tags: xml, sitemap

I have a list of static pages and a list of dynamic pages, I submitted it to Google console and it tells me this is wrong on every line where there's a URL tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>site.com/metadata/geo/sitemap.xml</loc>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/</loc>
      <priority>1.0</priority>
      <lastmod>2019-10-06</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/about</loc>
      <priority>0.5</priority>
      <lastmod>2019-10-06</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/best-practices</loc>
      <priority>0.5</priority>
      <lastmod>2019-10-06</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/dashboard</loc>
      <priority>0.5</priority>
      <lastmod>2019-10-06</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/dataset</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/dataset/83dc3401f86819de</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/metadata/geo/GSE9</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/faq</loc>
      <priority>0.5</priority>
      <lastmod>2019-10-06</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/guide</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/registry</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/bts</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>site.com/schema-playground</loc>
      <priority>0.5</priority>
      <lastmod>2019-10-06</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

I don't have much experience creating sitemaps so excuse my ignorance.  It seemed pretty simple from the docs I read but I guess I was wrong.

NOTE: replaced the full site address with "site.com" to make it simple. but just assume it's http:...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should specify full addresses with `http://` or `https://` part.

Edit:
`url` tags should be placed in own sitemap file under `urlset` tag. In your root file you should place 2 links to combine your `metadata/geo/sitemap.xml` file and rest of links

Comment: thank you I added a note, the actual sitemap has the full url. That's not the problem unfortunately

Comment: Also I didn't mention at first glance, you combine `sitemap` and `url` tags inside `sitemapindex`, but `url` tags should be placed inside `urlset` tag. Look here:
https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Comment: so like this: <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> urls here... </url>

Comment: do I have to repeat xmlns="sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" or just <urlset>

Comment: As I edit my answer, you should create another sitemap file with `urlset` and add it in your root file like you did with `site.com/metadata/geo/sitemap.xml`